# XSLT code to get only XML records with latest date

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

This is my input xml and I need to get only records with the latest date per **personId**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root>
    <Emp>
        <PersonId>10001</PersonId>
        <Child>
            <F1>JOE DOE</F1>
            <F2>SGP</F2>
            <F3>2010-01-06</F3>
            <F4>10001</F4>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <F1>Chris Tiu</F1>
            <F2>SGP</F2>
            <F3>2012-01-26</F3>
            <F4>10001</F4>
        </Child>
    </Emp>
    <Emp>
        <PersonId>10653</PersonId>
        <Child>
            <F1>Test Child</F1>
            <F2>SGP</F2>
            <F3>2008-11-29</F3>
            <F4>10653</F4>
        </Child>
        <Child>
            <F1>jane doe</F1>
            <F2>SGP</F2>
            <F3>1994-01-05</F3>
            <F4>10653</F4>
        </Child>
    </Emp>
</Root>
```

I already have the sorting logic and I am looking for a way to remove the old records from the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="cp1252" />
    <xsl:template match="/Root/Emp">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Child">
                <!-- concat year, month, day -->
                <xsl:sort order="descending" select="concat(substring(F3, 1, 4), substring(F3, 6, 2), substring(F3, 9, 2))" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That is my xsl code for sorting, it works but I don't know how to only get the records with the latest date.

Comment: Here is my XSL file.

Comment: Don't see it...

Comment: it says too many characters. how can i add code here

Comment: already added in the main post

Comment: It seems that `F3` date format is directly sortable as a string without needing to extract components so using `<xsl:sort select="F3" .../>` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">

    <xsl:copy>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">

    <xsl:copy>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>
```

would allow you to add

```
<xsl:template match="Child">
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Or don't use the `xsl:sort` in an `xsl:apply-templates` but rather use it with `xsl:for-each` and then you can directly inside of it use `<xsl:if test="position() = 1"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:if>`.

Comment: i seee.. can you tell me where to put this?<xsl:template match="Child">
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

Comment: Like any template you put that template as a child of the `xsl:stylesheet/xsl:transform` root element of your XSLT code.

Comment: i know this is very very late reply. But this worked. Thank you! :)